# Selective message notifications

Tags: iphone

Can you turn off all notifications (text, email, phone, etc) but a selective few senders at night?  I am on call after hours and the work computer sends out a text message. That is all I want to hear.

Answer (score 1):

The `Do not disturb` tool of the iPhone may provide what you are asking.

If you turn `Do not disturb` you'll be able to receive only the call from Favourite list of contacts. The only problem is that this service doesn't work for messages and therefore if you need to receive only message from a particular number, what I'm suggesting doesn't work for you.